# Find people that are not alive in 2016

Tags: logic, owl, protege, dlquery, manchester-syntax

I have an ontology, where `Person` is a class and `hasDeathYear` is a data property. I have to express the title in a *DL query*.

I can ask this:

> Person and hasDeathYear value 2016

but I cannot ask something like this:

> Person and hasDeathYear min 2016

where in place of `min` I would actually like to express "less than".

How to do it? *Is it possible*? A negative answer would also suffice for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the year is stored as value on which datatype facets are supported, you can do this with a DL query like:

Person **and** (hasDeathYear **some** xsd:int [<= 2016])

Some of these questions and answers have more examples:

- [Defining Protege class with expression of numerical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228328/defining-protege-class-with-expression-of-numerical-data)
- [Encoding mathematical properties in RDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134785/encoding-mathematical-properties-in-rdf)
- [How to express numeric intervals in datatype property in the ontology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489916/how-to-express-numeric-intervals-in-datatype-property-in-the-ontology)

Comment: No the `year` is not stored. Can you expand on this, *please*? By giving the query as you suggested, I am getting a syntax error and it expects a `Datatype name`, `not` or `{` in place of `<`.

Comment: @gsamaras Sorry, it should be xsd:int [<= 2016]. Ithink since of the linked questions probably showed that. I'm not sure what you mean by "the year is not stored". What's your data actually look like?

Comment: If you were a pomekon, you would be Alakazam, thanks! I meant that I hadn't store somewhere the year 2016, thanks JT!

Comment: @gsamaras if you don't have the year values stored as numbers somewhere, then this approach won't work.  You accepted it though, so I assume it worked for you, so I guess you do have years stored as numbers?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes of course. Sorry for the late response, but I am battling with my last query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785868/find-people-that-have-children-that-have-an-age-difference-of-at-least-10-years